# Erro em tempo de execução '13': Tipos incompatíveis

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Eu uso um sistema de planilhas no serviço que criamos na época que usávamos o Windows 7. Depois os computadores foram atualizados para o windows 10, face a descontinuação do 7. Ela foi criada a partir do excel do office 2000. Depois da última atualização do windows 10, toda vez que mando elas se atualizarem na matriz, elas apresentam a mensagem título. Até antes disso, nunca houve problemas algum com elas.

A subrotina que o Microsoft Visual Basic agora está apresentando "defeito" é esta:

```
Function FormataProcesso(NI)

Dim novoNi As String

    **novoNi = CStr(CDec(NI))**    <====

'------- primeiro completa com zeros para formatar como CNPJ ----

    novoNi = MaskOut(novoNi)

    If Len(novoNi) <= 15 Then Tamanho = 15 Else Tamanho = 17

    While (Len(novoNi) < Tamanho)

        novoNi = "0" & novoNi

    Wend
```

NI é o numero de CNPJ, que aparece puro na planilha, sem . ou -
Ao depurar, o módulo destaca a linha com a flecha como "defeituosa".

Alguém já conseguiu solucionar esse tipo de defeito?

Comment: Na hora que retorna esse erro, com aquela linha pintada de amarelo e a execução em pausa, aponte o mouse para `NI`. Vai aparecer uma tooltip com o valor do parâmetro `NI` no momento do erro. Então, edite sua pergunta, dizendo qual é esse valor.

Answer (score -1):

Tudo indica que o problema não está na migração do sistema operacional, mas sim, na origem dos dados que a macro está efetuando a leitura.

Se a função CDec for fornecida com uma sequência de texto que não possa ser convertida em um valor numérico, ela retornará o erro.

Veja esses dois exemplos, sendo que o primeiro roda normal e o segundo apresenta erro '13':

**1º Exemplo**

```
Sub exemplo1()

Dim dec1 As Variant
dec1 = CDec("1,001.000001")
MsgBox (dec1)

End Sub
```

**2º Exemplo**

```
Sub exemplo2()

Dim dec1 As Variant
dec1 = CDec("1,001.0000/1")
MsgBox (dec1)

End Sub
```